# Jquery Checkbox is checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, checkbox, slider

I am working on making a slider that has different prices using jQuery and a little rangeslider.js. I made everything work, but the second two numbers only change when I move the slider, not when I check the checkbox. I am trying to make the numbers change right when I click the checkbox.

```
$(document).on('input change', '#range-slider', '#voiceover', function() { //Listen to slider changes (input changes)       

    var v=$(this).val();
  var voiceOption = $('#voiceover');//Create a Variable (v), and store the value of the input change (Ex. Image 2 [imageURL])
  console.log(v);

$('#sliderStatus').html(videoDuration[v]);
$('#sliderPrice').html('<span>$'+videoSubtotal[v]+'.00</span>');

var totalPrice = parseInt(voiceoverSubtotal[v])+parseInt(videoSubtotal[v]);
  if(voiceOption.is(":checked")){
    $('#voiceoverspan').html('<span>$'+voiceoverSubtotal[v]+'.00</span>');
      $('#totalspan').html('<span>$'+totalPrice+'.00</span>');
  }
    else{
    $('#voiceoverspan').html('<span>$0.00</span>');
     $('#totalspan').html('<span>$'+videoSubtotal[v]+'.00</span>');
  }

  /*if(voiceOption.is(":checked") ){
    $('#totalspan').html('<span>$'+totalPrice+'.00</span>');
  }
  else{
    $('#totalspan').html('<span>$'+videoSubtotal[v]+'.00</span>');
  }*/
});
```

Thank you so much my codepen is here: https://codepen.io/2cheeky4you/pen/QqGKpy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated CodePen:** https://codepen.io/bhansa/pen/aLwGZo

You should add a change event to your checkbox and update the html data in the if statement.
Keep your checkbox change method out of the `input#range-slider` change method.

```
v = $("input#range-slider").val();

 voiceOption.on("change", function(){
    if(voiceOption.is(":checked")){
    $('#voiceoverspan').html('<span>$'+voiceoverSubtotal[v]+'.00</span>');
      $('#totalspan').html('<span>$'+totalPrice+'.00</span>');
  }
    else{
    $('#voiceoverspan').html('<span>$0.00</span>');
     $('#totalspan').html('<span>$'+videoSubtotal[v]+'.00</span>');
  }
  });
```

Comment: This works for the checkbox, but it doesn't change with the slider.

Comment: If you want to change the voiceover price with the slider too, add the code for it in your slider value change method. You cannot put both events together that was my point.

Comment: Oh!! That makes so much more sense! Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

You need to react to the change event on the checkbox:

```
$("#voiceover").on("change", doUpdate);
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that all of your code is wrapped in the change event for the slider.

```
$(document).on('input change', '#range-slider', '#voiceover', function() { //Listen to slider changes (input changes)
```

That means the check for the checkbox changing only happens when the slider changes too. Move this line

```
});
```

ABOVE your commented code. Then format the commented code at the bottom like this.

```
$('#checkBoxId').on('click', function() {
     if(this.checked) {
         if(voiceOption.is(":checked") ){
             $('#totalspan').html('<span>$'+totalPrice+'.00</span>');
         }
         else {
             $('#totalspan').html('<span>$'+videoSubtotal[v]+'.00</span>');
         }
     }
});
```

Comment: I tried it and it said: Unexpected Token, ILLEGAL. How would I fic that